# Making calls with Asterisk by Python

Tags: python, django, asterisk

I want to develop a project in django where the user can make calls using an Asterisk server. It uploads the audio and the numbers he want to call and the Asterisk makes the calls.

I have some knowledge in Asterisk, but do not know how best to connect Python to Asterisk. Searching found some methods, such as:

- AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface)
- Call File
- AJAM - the asynchronous Javascript Asterisk Manager

What I recommend for this project? And what better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In asterisk, the programming language does not matter.

I suggest you to take a look at [Asterisk AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI)

> **Asterisk Gateway Interface (AGI)** The Asterisk Gateway Interface is an
>   interface for adding functionality to Asterisk with many different
>   programming languages. Perl, PHP, C, Pascal, Bourne Shell - it's your
>   choice, really.

If you are looking for python libraries check the following:

Python

- Fats http://sourceforge.net/projects/fats/ FastAGI & AMI for the
  Twisted framework, MIT license. Full code test covered, Mock Object
  pattern examples.
- PyAstre https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyastre: Asterisk modules using
  Twisted framework.
- Python AGI http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst
- Python AGI bindings py-Asterisk Manager interface with Plone/Zope
  atasterisk
- StarPy http://starpy.sourceforge.net/: Asterisk Twisted modules for
  AMI clients and FastAGI servers

Comment: Just as a shameless plug, the Asterisk project itself uses StarPy extensively for its Test Suite. If twisted is acceptable for your project, you may want to consider it, as it is fairly reliable and well used.